# WORDPRESS.ORG Parse error: syntax error in index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm using wordpress.org making a custom theme and I'm a complete PHP noob. It keeps saying something about bad syntax and my website just won't appear. I wasn't hacked I'm making my own custom theme and I just don't know how to properly close everything. Anyway here is my index.php page. What am I missing? What am I not closing correctly? I would greatly appreciate the help!

```
              <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="posts">
        <div id="post">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="post-thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div><!--POST-THUMB-->

                <p class="lit"><?php the_content(''); ?></p>

    <div id="price_buy">
    <ul>
<li><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", true);?>$</li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "buy", true);?>">BUY</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>                  


    <div id="share"><span class="cats">MORE:<?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <p>SHARE</p>
<ul>

<?php if (get_option('lp_share_post_facebook') == "true") { ?>
<li>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>?t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Post to Facebook">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook-big.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
</li>

<?php } ?><?php if (get_option('lp_share_post_twitter') == "true") { ?>
<li>
<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Post to Twitter">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/twitter-big.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
</li>

<?php } ?><?php if (get_option('lp_share_post_email') == "true") { ?>
<li>
<a href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;body=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Email a Friend">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/email.png" alt="Email" /></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>

    </div><!--POST-->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What's the error? In which line? All the information you need should be in the error message. We don't know it so we cannot even help you. *edit:* The error seems to be *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 51*... I assume you have to call `endwhile;` as well somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you get started on these tutorials: [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) & [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/First_Steps_With_WordPress)

This should probably fix your problem for now:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="posts">
      <div id="post">
        <h2>
          <a href="%3C?php%20the_permalink();%20?%3E"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
        <div class="post-thumb">
          <a href="%3C?php%20the_permalink();%20?%3E"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        </div><!--POST-THUMB-->
        <p class="lit">
          <?php the_content(''); ?>
        </p>
        <div id="price_buy">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", true);?>$
            </li>
            <li>
              <a target="_blank" href="%3C?php%20echo%20get_post_meta($post-%3EID,">"&gt;BUY</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="share">
          <span class="cats">MORE:<?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
          <p>
            SHARE
          </p>
          <ul>
            <?php if (get_option('lp_share_post_facebook') == "true") { ?>
            <li>
              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%3C?php%20the_permalink();?%3E?t=%3C?php%20the_title();%20?%3E" title="Post to Facebook"><img src="%3C?php%20echo%20get_template_directory_uri();%20?%3E/images/facebook-big.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
            </li><?php } ?><?php if (get_option('lp_share_post_twitter') == "true") { ?>
            <li>
              <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=%3C?php%20the_title();%20?%3E%C2%A0-%C2%A0%3C?php%20the_permalink();%20?%3E" title="Post to Twitter"><img src="%3C?php%20echo%20get_template_directory_uri();%20?%3E/images/twitter-big.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
            </li><?php } ?><?php if (get_option('lp_share_post_email') == "true") { ?>
            <li>
              <a href="mailto:?subject=%3C?php%20the_title();%20?%3E&amp;body=%3C?php%20the_permalink();%20?%3E" title="Email a Friend"><img src="%3C?php%20echo%20get_template_directory_uri();%20?%3E/images/email.png" alt="Email"></a>
            </li><?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!--POST-->
      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      <?php get_footer(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: yes except now I got WAY more problems. Absolutely nothing works, not one aspect of my blog i spent hours designing even works at all. the theme is there, I activate it. It has an index and a stylesheet and I know html/css so i coded it correctly it worked in my browser but now when I slice it up and PHP it NOT ONE DESIGN ELEMENT SHOWS. the content is all visible so It's not the PHP crashing but I just cant figure out why NOTHING absolutely NOTHING stylewise shows up. very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

On line 3 and 4 you have an if and a while (written in PHP's alternate control structure style) which have not been closed.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

You will need to close these at the appropriate time with

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in your code.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! i seriously love you so much, thank you